# What is the equivalent of this BeautifulSoup expression in Xpath?

Tags: xpath, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape this [link](https://www.stepstone.de/stellenangebote--JAVA-Software-Entwickler-m-w-d-Sueddeutschland-TECCON-Consulting-Engineering-GmbH--6582908-inline.html?suid=011f441f-d609-4eb4-8dfc-889b0a076f4a&rltr=1_1_25_dynrl_m_0_0_0_0) using scrapy and BeautifulSoup but for some reason BeautifulSoup is not working in the spider, it's only working in scrapy shell. I know this might sound silly, however, how to translate that to Xpath?

```
soup.find('li', {'class': 'at-listing__list-icons_location'})
```

I tried

```
response.xpath('//li[contains(text(),"at-listing__list icons_location")]/../descendant::text()').extract()
```

Please refer to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63362145/scrapy-with-splash-settings-works-in-scrapy-shell-fails-otherwise) in which I included the logs I was trying to make things work using splash and BeautifulSoup but all attempts failed so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're trying to get the 3 values 'Süddeutschland', 'Feste Anstellung' and 'Vollzeit'?
In that case the below xpath works for me:

```
response.xpath('//*[has-class("at-listing__list-icons_location")]/../descendant::text()').extract()
```

I think the problem in your xpath is that you're trying to look in the text for value 'at-listing__list icons_location', instead of the class.